# Book recommendation: Disorder (in Condensed Matter)

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations

I'm after a book about disorder in a general and introductory way. I already read about diffusion in disordered media and all the theoretical background (i.e. the math),  but I feel that I missed some sort of qualitative introduction about why we study disorder in condensed matter, what are its implications, what are we after when we study a system with disorder, what kind of test we can do to a system like this, what's interesting about it.

If you can recommend me a book about this questions (and/or more) I would appreciate it!